# Whats the MAX Length for USB, HDMI/VGA and Headphone cables

Tags: usb, hdmi, vga

I like to put the box away from user in a network layout.

So, there will be LED monitor, with either VGA or HDMI, then two Headphones and two USB 2.0 for Mouse and Keyboard.

I like to know whats the reasonable (on price) max length I can get from end user to the box. Please write in meters, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For USB roughly 20 bucks would most likely get you around 3 meters of cord, at least that's the price I pay, HDMI, you're looking at that same price fore a little under a meter, headphone extension cables are cheap you can get those off ebay for 2 bucks with free shipping. Why not go wireless?

Comment: maybe I can go wireless on headphone and mouse, but how can I go wireless on Monitor, so since one has to be wired, so make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a physical limit in the length of USB cables (~5 meter for USB 2.0): http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/cable/USB-cable-length.html

Comment: So how about VGA/HDMI and headphone, whats the max length of it